# How to output an inhereted widget on multiple pages

Tags: flutter, dart

I’m new to flutter and I wanted to output a text field result from a form on to multiple screens it works for one page but when I try to call it on another page it show an error saying I haven’t initialized a static value but I have on the form page and if I initialize it it won’t out put the text fields result it show an error saying there is no text but I want it to say like you have nothing or be blank and when a user fill the form it will display the result plus a widget Help please

Comment: First, please try too use punctuation. Commas and periods and all that, you know. Second, which "static value" haven't you initialized?  Third, I think you might want to use Provider with a Listenable for this

Comment: Thank you so much @frank06 I’ve figured it out